# What's the difference between `declare global` and `declare namespace global` in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a global declaration file where I have to use an `import` statement, thus making it a module, therefore for exposing global types I have to declare them over the global namespace.

Firstly I tried this:

```
import { SomeType } from 'some-package';

declare namespace global {
  interface ShouldBeGlobal {}
}
```

This doesn't throw a syntax error, but it doesn't work how I'd expect: the interface `ShouldBeAGlobal` is not exposed globally.

However, this works and it's exposed everywhere:

```
import { SomeType } from 'some-package';

declare global {
  interface ShouldBeGlobal {}
}
```

Why doesn't the first one works?

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you're not exposing anything to the global namespace because you're actually creating a new namespace called `global`. An easy way to confirm this is by commenting your `import` statement, thus making your declaration file a global declaration file (those that don't have `import`/`export`), and try to access `global.ShouldBeGlobal`—you'll see that it's available.

The second way is the correct way to expose types into the global namespace (the real one). Similarly as above, if you want to understand what the `namespace global` statement is actually doing, you can also change it to this:

```
import { SomeType } from 'some-package';

declare global {
  interface ShouldBeGlobal {}

  // not that you don't need the declare keyword here again, because it's already nested on a declare block
  namespace global {
    interface AnotherInterface {}
  }
}
```

Now in any file you should still be able to access the `ShouldBeGlobal` interface, but now you also have `global.AnotherInterface`, because now you created a new namespace called `global` inside the global namespace.